# JQuery Attr is not function

Tags: jquery, attr

I try to add attribute of option by using JQuery. I run this code.

```
 $("option[value='430']").attr("selected","selected");
```

It return **TypeError: $(...).attr is not a function(…)**

I cannot saw my error. Where is the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: `Attr` or `attr`??? What is the exact error message?

Comment: [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/nu5d7v8c/) should be ok..as well as using `.prop()` you should check some other error

Comment: @A.Wolff I editted the message.

Comment: Check `$("option[value='430']").length` - if it's 0, you need to work on your selector.

Comment: So i guess, `$` isn't refering to jQuery

Comment: @mpf82, it returns undefined

Comment: Are you sure, you are using jQuery? I agree with @A.Wolff

Comment: So at least, are you including jQuery? Or are you using any CMS (wordpress e.g)?

Comment: What @A.Wolff said - `$` does not stand for `jQuery` in your case. Make sure you've included the jquery js file. Check your console for 404 errors, maybe the file can not be found.

Comment: try `jQuery("option[value='430']").attr("selected","selected");`

Comment: or `(function($){ $("option[value='430']").attr("selected","selected"); })(jQuery)`

Comment: @PranavCBalan, it return ` jQuery is not defined(…) `

Comment: yes, I sure for that. <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/` , put  `http://` before the link or `//` .... otherwise it looks for the directory

Comment: I solved it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I was working live on the a website. I changed it. First, by using php, I got the file on new document. Then I tried to add attribute. The code when I wrote at first was successful. I think that JQuery was not loaded. Now, I loaded it.

This is true code:

```
 $("option[value='430']").attr("selected","selected");
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

In your code `$` referring to some other library and in that library `attr()` method is `undefined`.

Also you need to add the library before the code. And the library referencing as you commented is wrong, since it's cdn link you need to put `http://` (or `https://`) or `//` before it otherwise it looks for the directory.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js" />
```

Then use `jQuery` instead of `$` to refer the library or use a closures with argument `$` and move the code inside.

```
jQuery("option[value='430']").attr("selected","selected");
```

or

```
(function($){ 
   $("option[value='430']").attr("selected","selected"); 
})(jQuery)
```

or

```
jQuery(function($){ 
   $("option[value='430']").attr("selected","selected"); 
})
```

---

Also go through the docs of **[`jQuery.coConflict()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/)** that may helpful for using different libraries where `$` have special meaning.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using  `$("option[value='430']").Attr("selected","selected");` instead of  `$("option[value='430']").attr("selected","selected");`

[image]

The correct method is `.attr(name, value)`.
You can also use `.prop()` method to retrieve and change DOM properties such as the checked, selected, or disabled state of form elements.

Comment: No. I wrote little attr. By the way, I solved it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

in jQuery 1.4.1 you can use the .setAttribute method, for example:

```
$("option[value='430']").setAttribute('selected','selected');
```

Answer (score -2):

Try following :

```
$("option[value='430']").attr("selected",true);
```

Comment: Try to use parent element as well like :

$('select').find('option[value"430"]').attr('selected', true);

Comment: It returns $(...).find is not a function(…)